# How can I dodge the Grey Prince's frantic swings?

Tags: hollow-knight

I'm fighting "[Grey Prince Zote](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Prince_Zote)" and I'm having a real hard time. Most of his attacks are broadcasted pretty well, and are mostly predictable so I know how to dodge them (even if I can't pull it off).

But his "Frantic swings" are really hard for me to dodge. There are mainly two different things I have tried:

- I can jump over him.
- I can use shade cloak to dash through him as he comes towards me.

But neither of these works because he turns around so quickly. I usually end up shade cloaking through him the first time, trying to jump out of the way, and then getting hit immediately because his nail has a really long reach.

I can't beat him because this one attack gets me every single time. Is there a better way to dodge this attack?

Comment: I seriously this was about Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion at first :)

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this particular attack for so long until I stumbled upon an awesome way to dodge it by accident. Since this technique helped me so much, I wanted to share it in case it could help someone else.

Basically, the monarch wings are reset every time you boop someone on the head, so you can take advantage of this to stay in air above him for a really long time. It also slows the pace of the fight a little bit, giving you room to breath.

Try doing this:

- When he first comes towards you, jump up as high as you can (potentially with your double jump too).
- When you fall down, he will probably be right underneath you. Use this time to downward slash at Zote. When you hit him, it will reset your monarch wings, so you can jump up again. This allows you to stay up in the air for a really long time.

Since this is somewhat hard to describe, I made a video of me demonstrating this technique (ignore the fact that I died :P):

You can see me doing this technique at 0:50 and again at 1:17.

One thing to keep in mind when you're trying this is that sometimes, Zote will trip *just* before you would have slashed at him, so you miss him on the floor and then fall into him. Staying up as high as possible will help minimize this possibility, but you may need to use your dash at the last second to avoid falling into him.

To maximize the effectiveness of this approach, I highly recommend Longnail/Mark of Pride to make downslashing easier, and Dream Shield so you can get a little bit more damage in while doing this.